# (Card Layout) Setting Card Name of CardPanels for JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, layout, jcombobox, cardlayout

guys. My project's design is a combination of hard coded design and design made using the GUI Builder of Netbeans. I decided to use the GUI Builder for RAD and rapid designing since we're behind schedule.

So my problem is how to assign a name for the cardpanels when using Card Layout for a panel. I know that you can simply write `cardContainerPanel.add(card1Panel,"card1")` if not using the GUI Builder. `card1` as the `String` identifier of the card1Panel. But what I would like to be able to do is to pass a `String variable` as the card name.

Like,

```
String card1 = "card1";
```

then
`cardContainerPanel.add(card1Panel, card1)`

1.) **How can i do this on Netbeans GUI Builder using the Properties option of a panel when it only takes what you type on Card Name as String**

[image]

I need to switch to different cards during an `itemChange` event on a `JComboBox`.

Here's what I've written so far.

```
private void settingsComboBoxItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {                                                  
        CardLayout cl = (CardLayout)(cardContainerPanel.getLayout());
        cl.show(cardContainerPanel, (String)evt.getItem());
    }                                                 

    private void loadSettingsComboxBoxModel(){
        String HOME = "Home";
        String ADMIN = "Administration";
        String ADMIN_CURC = "Administration > Curriculum";
        String ADMIN_DISCOUNTS = "Administration > Discounts";
        String ADMIN_SECTIONS = "Administration > Sections";
        String ADMIN_USERS = "Administration > Users";
        String ADMIN_SCHED = "Administration > Schedule";
        String ADMIN_YRLEVEL = "Administration > Year Level";
        String PAYMENT = "Payment";
        String REGISTRATION = "Registration";
        String STUDENTS = "Students";
        String FACULTY = "Faculty";
        String REPORTS = "Reports";
        String SECTIONS = "Sections";

        String settingsComboBoxItems[] = 
            {HOME,ADMIN,ADMIN_CURC,ADMIN_DISCOUNTS,
                ADMIN_SECTIONS,ADMIN_USERS,ADMIN_SCHED,
                ADMIN_YRLEVEL,PAYMENT,REGISTRATION,STUDENTS,FACULTY,REPORTS,SECTIONS};
        DefaultComboBoxModel dcm = new DefaultComboBoxModel(settingsComboBoxItems);
        settingsComboBox.setModel(dcm); 
    }
```

[image]

[image]

I'd appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is irrelevant that you hard code the name of the card in the IDE.

What is relevant is the card names used when you want to swap cards. In this case there is no reason you can't use a variable to specify the card name you want to swap to.

In fact it looks like you are using a combo box to select the card you want to display. So all you need to do is make sure that the card name is the same as the value displayed in the combo box.

Then in your ItemListener you just use the following to swap cards:

```
cardLayout.show(cards, (String)evt.getItem());
```

See the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for a working example.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yeah, I actually went to the oracle.com page about "How to Use Card Layout" but how can I tell a specific combobox model item to which panel it is tied using just the GUI Builder. I can simply use cardLayout.show(cards, (String)evt.getItem()); but i can't tie an item in combo box to the panel it has to show.

Comment: You just said you can enter "homeCard" in the IDE. So therefore you also need to have "homeCard" in the combo box. However based on the code you posted the card name should be "Home", the same as the value displayed in the combo box. The second card name should be "Administration".

Comment: Thanks for the information. I was able to solve it but using an alternative way which is by using addLayoutComponent(cardPanelToShow,stringVariable);
cl.show(cardContainerPanel, (String)evt.getItem());

Comment: I guess your solution was much easier and has less code. Thanks. I appreciate it. I'll edit my post with the addLayoutComponent() as well to help others.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it using the `addLayoutComponent()` method which adds panels to the Card Layout object and accepts a string variable as its second argument.

```
        String HOME = "Home";
        String ADMIN = "Administration";
        String ADMIN_CURC = "Administration > Curriculum";
        String ADMIN_DISCOUNTS = "Administration > Discounts";
        String ADMIN_SECTIONS = "Administration > Sections";
        String ADMIN_USERS = "Administration > Users";
        String ADMIN_SCHED = "Administration > Schedule";
        String ADMIN_YRLEVEL = "Administration > Year Level";
        String PAYMENT = "Payment";
        String REGISTRATION = "Registration";
        String STUDENTS = "Students";
        String FACULTY = "Faculty";
        String REPORTS = "Reports";
        String SECTIONS = "Sections";

        String settingsComboBoxItems[] = 
            {HOME,ADMIN,ADMIN_CURC,ADMIN_DISCOUNTS,
                ADMIN_SECTIONS,ADMIN_USERS,ADMIN_SCHED,
                ADMIN_YRLEVEL,PAYMENT,REGISTRATION,STUDENTS,FACULTY,REPORTS,SECTIONS};
        DefaultComboBoxModel dcm = new DefaultComboBoxModel(settingsComboBoxItems);

//constructor
    public UserManagementGUI() {
            initComponents();
            loadUsersList();
            settingsComboBox.setModel(dcm);
        }

private void settingsComboBoxItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {                                                  
        CardLayout cl = (CardLayout)(cardContainerPanel.getLayout());
        cl.addLayoutComponent(homePermissionsPanel, HOME);
        cl.addLayoutComponent(administrationPermissionsPanel, ADMIN);
        cl.show(cardContainerPanel, (String)evt.getItem());
    }
```

Comment: Steps:
1.) Declare String variables to hold the cards Identifiers.
2.) Store the declared Strings to an array. 
3.) Declare a DefaulComboBoxModel object and pass the array to initialize it
4.) Set the combo box's model to the DefaultComboBoxModel object holding the array
5.) Add you panels to the CardLayout object cl using the addLayoutComponent() method.

Comment: Not sure what the point of setting two constraints is for. How do you access the other 15 panels? Why do you set the constraints every time? The constraints should be assigned when the panels are created.

Comment: Don't worry I actually took your advice but you know I just thought maybe I can set a different name for every constraint which is different on the model item's name. I know it's kind of redundant that's why I still took your advice to set similar names for combo box item and the card's(panel) identifier.